# Selecting first td in the first table with CSS 3

Tags: css

Say for example I have:

```
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And

```
td { width:10px; height:10px; }
```

What I want to do is apply a style to the first td, of the first table.

I would have expected:

```
#container table:first-child td:first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

However it does not work? Please advise!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
#container table:first-child tr:first-child td:first-child { background: red; }
```

Seems to work.
Note that under IE, you will need to have a !DOCTYPE declaration in your html to get support for :first-child.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Answer (score 1):

To select only the first table within the div:

```
div#container table:nth-child(1) tr td {
    color: #888;
}
```

To select only the first td of the first table within the div:

```
div#container table:nth-child(1) tr td:nth-child(1) {
    color: #444;
}
```

For me this works easier if you want to change it to a second table or second tablecell

```
div#container table:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1) {
    color: #888;
}
```