# How to select first and last <th> only?

Tags: css, html-table

My table has `id="mytable"`. I'm trying to apply some CSS on the first and last `<th>` only. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
#mytable th:first,
#mytable th:last{
 //css goes here
}
```

Comment: correct answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3729911/961631

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
#mytable th:last-child, #mytable th:first-child {
 //css goes here
}
```

Comment: And `:first-child` respectively. +1!

Comment: Remember `:first-child` and `:last-child` attribute selectors are still not supported for IE6

Comment: @Alan Are there any stats on % of browsers that still use IE6?

Comment: If you really need assertion to whether you should or shouldn't use something, check out http://caniuse.com/. Whether you should support ancient browsers or not, depends (imho) entirely on your targeted audience.

Comment: this selects all th, not only the fist one https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/LYmaPmE?editors=1100

Answer (score -1):

For CSS

```
#myTable thead tr th:first,
#myTable thead tr th:last{
  /*CSS goes here*/
}
```

Using Jquery (for last child only):

```
$("#mytable th:last-child").css({

/*CSS goes here*/

});
```

Comment: Nothing in question mentions jQuery